# Why should I upgrade from Angular 6 to Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8, angular9

The projects I have been working on for 2 years was made of Angular 6. It has been a long time when the current version is Angular 9.  Please explain why should I upgrade to Angular 9 and my prime motive is better performance. Or it is better to stay with Angular 6.

If better then what are all things I should take into consideration while upgrading directly from 6 to 9? or I should upgrade from 6 to 7 then 7 to 8, etc

Comment: Preferably upgrade your typeScript version to latest supported by angular 9 and then upgrade angular cli to a stable version of 8 to finally be able to upgrade it to 9.

Comment: This can be useful for you [link](https://angularjobs.com/update/angular-9-update-features-ivy-aot/)

Comment: Upgrading from 6 to 9 directly not recommended as per https://update.angular.io/#6.0:9.0

Answer (score 2):

The latest version has some new features given here: [Angular 9 features](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/top-new-features-of-angular-9)

I'm afraid that your cannot upgrade from angular 6 to 9 directly. You may need to update to the latest of Angular 7, followed by 8, and then 9. Check out [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to the latest version is always beneficial in the long term as most of the dependencies gets deprecated and which may create problem afterwards.

As of now Angular 9 has seen some tremendous changes including the shift to Ivy engine which is much faster and has better debugging compared to the previous versions.

And Angular 10 has also been released now.